# EC2 vs Elastic Beanstalk vs Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have simple API, with connection to DB, calls to FB API etc.
What is the best way to serve it.

1) I have started with EC2 first.
Good: Cheap enough. I can control everything
Bad: Long set up process. Need to control everything. Set up monitoring tools etc by myself. Keep in mind a lot.

2) Next I have moved NodeJS to EB and move DB to RDS.
Good: Just commit a code, all other things handled by service
Bad: Load Balancer + Multiple instance + RDS costs a lot.

3) Lambda, thinking about moving to Lambda + API Gateway setup
It is look easy to implement, monitoring and support
Have no idea how much money it will cost.
I know that there is a lot of configuration inside.

Do you have any suggestion what will be the best for simple API? 
Also I thinking about moving only picture generation to Lambda, 
and keep simple API like AUTH, GET users etc on EB.

Comment: if you are use to ubuntu/linux take a look at Digital Ocean too as a place for your nodejs + db

Comment: This is too broad kindly update the question with your configs traffic patterns i.e  users also this is not coding related question and it might get flagged soon.

Comment: Did you also consider AWS Fargate for a more managed solution? Fargate can run your project as a Docker container and you won't have to worry about any operating system. https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/

Comment: Your "Bad" description of Elastic Beanstalk is completely false. Load Balancer, Multiple Instances and RDS are all optional with Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the processing logic does not exceed 5 minutes, then Option 3 will be definitely desired - as you write functions and deploy them in Lambda. No other deployment and auto scaling worries.

Of course, subject to the other factors like dependency on third party libraries for your logic, and compatibility with Lambda underlying image.